# expect ping script skipping send step

Tags: linux, bash, tcl, expect

I am trying to ping 4 different IP address after login to a remote switch using expect,login part works fine and the first 2 ping command (send); but it skips the 3rd ping command and go for 4th ping. And most of the time before showing the ping summary it exits the script.

My Script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
 spawn telnet 192.168.xx.xx
 expect "Username:" 
 send "username\r"
 expect "Password:"
 send "password\r"
 expect ">"
 send "ping -c 20 192.168.1.10\r"
 expect ">"
 send "ping -c 20 192.168.10.22\r"
 expect ">"
 send "ping -c 20 192.168.10.33\r"
 expect ">"
 send "ping -c 20 192.168.11.10\r"
 expect ">"
 send "quit\r" # command to exit from switch 
 expect eof
```

I have tried adding "sleep 4" before every send command but the results are same.

Output:

```
<switch>ping -c 20 192.168.1.20
  PING 192.168.1.20: 56  data bytes, press CTRL_C to break
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=1 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=2 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=3 ttl=255 time=101 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=4 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=5 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=6 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=7 ttl=255 time=102 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=8 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=9 ttl=255 time=3 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=10 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=11 ttl=255 time=108 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=12 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=13 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=14 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=15 ttl=255 time=130 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=16 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=17 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=18 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=19 ttl=255 time=160 ms
    Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=56 Sequence=20 ttl=255 time=1 ms

  --- 192.168.1.20 ping statistics ---
    20 packet(s) transmitted
    20 packet(s) received
    0.00% packet loss
    round-trip min/avg/max = 1/31/160 ms

<switch>ping -c 20 192.168.10.22
  PING 192.168.10.22: 56  data bytes, press CTRL_C to break
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=1 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=2 ttl=255 time=12 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=3 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=4 ttl=255 time=35 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=5 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=6 ttl=255 time=16 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=7 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=8 ttl=255 time=29 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=9 ttl=255 time=4 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=10 ttl=255 time=39 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=11 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=12 ttl=255 time=57 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=13 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=14 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=15 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=16 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=17 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=18 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=19 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.10.22: bytes=56 Sequence=20 ttl=255 time=2 ms

  --- 192.168.10.22 ping statistics ---
    20 packet(s) transmitted
    20 packet(s) received
    0.00% packet loss
    round-trip min/avg/max = 1/10/57 ms

<switch>ping -c 20 192.168.11.10
  PING 192.168.11.10: 56  data bytes, press CTRL_C to break
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=1 ttl=255 time=4 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=2 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=3 ttl=255 time=44 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=4 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=5 ttl=255 time=57 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=6 ttl=255 time=3 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=7 ttl=255 time=4 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=8 ttl=255 time=4 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=9 ttl=255 time=3 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=10 ttl=255 time=3 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=11 ttl=255 time=3 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=12 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=13 ttl=255 time=2 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=14 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=15 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=16 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=17 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=18 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=19 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    Reply from 192.168.11.10: bytes=56 Sequence=20 ttl=255 time=1 ms
    [rousseau@localhost script]$
```

As you can see, it skips the 3rd ping (checked several times) and exited before the 4th ping summery. Can anyone please help fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be running into a timeout issue. Default timeout for Expect is 10 seconds. 20 pings will take more than that approx.

use the following command in the beginning of the script:

`set timeout 60`

to set it to 1 min.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! timeout fixed it. I have passed a very frustrating day fixing this. cheers..!

Comment: you are welcome 
@glenn jackman: thanks for fixing the values.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's timing out. You might try something like

```
send "password\r"
expect ">"
foreach ip {192.168.1.10 192.168.10.22 192.168.10.33 192.168.11.10} {
    send "ping -c 20 $ip\r"
    expect {
        timeout {puts "Timed out waiting for response from $ip"}
        ">"
    }
}
send "quit\r"
```

You can experiment with setting the `timeout` value if you find you're getting timeouts, for example `set timeout 20`.

Also, I find this command invaluable for developing expect scripts: `exp_internal 1` -- add it at the top of your script.